# FPDF setting 2 consecutive values in one cell

Tags: php, fpdf

I just need to find out how to set 2 values from MySQL database in a FPDF. The values will be consecutive with a 'dash' in between them. Here is an example of what I want to do.

```
$pdf->Cell(110, 7,$address1 ' - ', $address2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a comma but should be using the dot '.'.  FPF is seeing these as different arguments separated by commas.

```
// this will work (note the dots instead of the comma)
$pdf->Cell(110, 7,$address1 . ' - ' . $address2);

// I prefer this: it is easier to read
$fullAddress = $address1 . ' - ' . $address2;
$pdf->Cell(110, 7,$fullAddress);
```